# Ansible - handle the fluentbit config update

Tags: ansible

I have following fluentbit input config file:

```
[INPUT]
    name    tail
    tag     tail_fluent_bit
    path    /var/log/fluent-bit.log

[INPUT]
    name       tail
    tag        tail_messages
    path       /var/log/messages
    multiline  on
```

I wanted to add another key value to each `INPUT` block. I was thinking to read this file line by line using Ansible through `with_lines` module and convert to dictionary of key-value pair and generate a list of inputs and then add the required key.

For example, if I wanted to add `multiline` key with value as `on`, I should be able to add that to each and every `INPUT` block if doesn't exist.

With my above approach, I believe I'm doing over-engineering because I have to trim spaces in each line and split by spaces again to make key-value pair, but my space length is not constant.

So this is what my output should be:

```
[INPUT]
    name       tail
    tag        tail_fluent_bit
    path       /var/log/fluent-bit.log
    multiline  on

[INPUT]
    name       tail
    tag        tail_messages
    path       /var/log/messages
    multiline  on
```

In above output, please note that `multiline    on` is added in first `INPUT` block.

I need some direction here.

Answer (score 1):

Given the file

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/fluentbit.conf 
[INPUT]
    name    tail
    tag     tail_fluent_bit
    path    /var/log/fluent-bit.log

[INPUT]
    name       tail
    tag        tail_messages
    path       /var/log/messages
    multiline  on
```

Parse the file on your own. Read the file

```yaml
    - command: cat /tmp/fluentbit.conf
      register: fluentbit_conf_out
```

and declare the structure

```yaml
  fluentbit_conf: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for line in fluentbit_conf_out.stdout_lines|select %}
    {% if line is regex('\[.*\]') %}
    - {{ line[1:-1] }}:
    {% else %}
        {{ line|split|first }}: '{{ line|split|last }}'
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  fluentbit_conf:
  - INPUT:
      name: tail
      path: /var/log/fluent-bit.log
      tag: tail_fluent_bit
  - INPUT:
      multiline: 'on'
      name: tail
      path: /var/log/messages
      tag: tail_messages
```

Declare the defaults and update the configuration

```yaml
  fluentbit_conf_defaults:
    - INPUT:
        multiline: 'on'

  fluentbit_conf_update: "{{ fluentbit_conf_defaults|
                             product(fluentbit_conf)|
                             map('combine', recursive=true) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  fluentbit_conf_update:
  - INPUT:
      multiline: 'on'
      name: tail
      path: /var/log/fluent-bit.log
      tag: tail_fluent_bit
  - INPUT:
      multiline: 'on'
      name: tail
      path: /var/log/messages
      tag: tail_messages
```

Write the file

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/fluentbit.conf
        content: |
          {% for i in fluentbit_conf_update %}
          {% for section,conf in i.items() %}
          [{{ section }}]
          {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
              {{ '%-11s%-11s' % (k, v) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

Test the difference running with the options *--check --diff*

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --check --diff
  ...
TASK [copy] ***********************************************************************************
--- before: /tmp/fluentbit.conf
+++ after: /home/admin/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-3967647klph_pe0/tmpd8vimcjo
@@ -1,10 +1,12 @@
 [INPUT]
-    name    tail
-    tag     tail_fluent_bit
-    path    /var/log/fluent-bit.log
+    multiline  on         
+    name       tail       
+    tag        tail_fluent_bit
+    path       /var/log/fluent-bit.log
 
 [INPUT]
-    name       tail
+    multiline  on         
+    name       tail       
     tag        tail_messages
     path       /var/log/messages
-    multiline  on
+
```

and write the file

```ini
shell> cat /tmp/fluentbit.conf
[INPUT]
    multiline  on         
    name       tail       
    tag        tail_fluent_bit
    path       /var/log/fluent-bit.log

[INPUT]
    multiline  on         
    name       tail       
    tag        tail_messages
    path       /var/log/messages
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    fluentbit_conf: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for line in fluentbit_conf_out.stdout_lines|select %}
      {% if line is regex('\[.*\]') %}
      - {{ line[1:-1] }}:
      {% else %}
          {{ line|split|first }}: '{{ line|split|last }}'
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

    fluentbit_conf_defaults:
      - INPUT:
          multiline: 'on'
    fluentbit_conf_update: "{{ fluentbit_conf_defaults|
                               product(fluentbit_conf)|
                               map('combine', recursive=true) }}"

  tasks:

    - command: cat /tmp/fluentbit.conf
      register: fluentbit_conf_out
      check_mode: false
    - debug:
        var: fluentbit_conf

    - debug:
        var: fluentbit_conf_update
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/fluentbit.conf
        content: |
          {% for i in fluentbit_conf_update %}
          {% for section,conf in i.items() %}
          [{{ section }}]
          {% for k,v in conf.items() %}
              {{ '%-11s%-11s' % (k, v) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}

          {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however this works only when there is [INPUT] section, however at times in the same conf I may have other sections like [FILTER]. The multiline key value should only be added to [INPUT] section.